# Postgres to Oracle translation

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, syntax

How can I get this Postgres statement to parse into Oracle 11g?

```
UPDATE teams as new 
  SET counter=old.counter, 
      task_counter=old.task_counter 
FROM teams as old
WHERE new.is_old=0 
  AND old.is_old=1 
  AND new.name=old.name 
  AND new.county=old.county;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LeorA: why do you think that is a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE teams
  SET (counter, task_counter) = (select counter, task_counter 
                                 FROM teams old
                                 WHERE old.is_old = 1 
                                   AND teams.name = old.name   
                                   AND teams.county = old.county)
where is_old = 0
```

This assumes that the sub-select will only return a single row for each name/county/is_old combination.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to execute an update with a join, ie `UPDATE ... FROM`. This doesn't seem to be supported directly, but can be done using `UPDATE` with a subquery.

See:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2009/10/22/oracle-update-with-join-ndash-revisited.aspx
- http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:556373000346392260
- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=399752
- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=399246&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

One handy Oracle technique is to use a MERGE for these tricky updates.

```
Merge into teams new 
From (
  Select counter,
         task_counter
  From   teams 
  Where  is_old = 1) old
On (new.is_old = 0          and
    new.name   = old.name   and
    new.county = old.county   )
when matched then update
set counter      = old.counter and
    task_counter = old.task_counter
```